# how to git uncomit some files but not lose them?

Tags: git

I had some unstaged files. I added them with git add.
Then by mistake (I thought I had created another branch but didn't) I committed them.

So now I have one commit more in my *original_branch*.

How do I uncommit this last commit?

Take into account that :

- I don't want to lose my files
- My objective is to have these files as I had them in the beginning, uncommited and ready to be committed in a different branch

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you haven't pushed yet upstream, you can:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

This will "remove" the last commit but will preserve the files ready-to-be-committed.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting? I use this method regularly and it never lets me down :) Seriously, if the downvoter has a better solution please post it here

Answer (score 1):

You can simply undo the last commit:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

This will keep the accidentally-commited files in tact.

Alternatively, if you have other changes in the last commit you still want to retain but at the same time  remove the accidentally-commited files, try:

```
git reset HEAD^ -- file1 file2 file3...
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

(where file1 file2 file3... are the files you want to remove from the last commit).

Comment: I don't know why someone gave you a minus. I applied your solution that and it worked. it would be nice that any minus point came with an explanation